# how to change snapshot of app switcher in Background in ios7

Tags: ios7

Snapshot is not refreshed after changing ui in the background before calling completion handler in ios7.
i am changing label text in background with notificationcenter in view controller when app performbackgroundfetchhandler in app switcher it does not change view controller label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up finding my own solution, 
when notificaton comes, it shows snapshot changes take place, if we are updating views when notification comes

Comment: Can you show us with code how you achieved this please? I'm curious. Thank you

Comment: when you implement push notification and when it comes on device then os updates app switcher with latest screen shot.